# convert CIDR to subnet mask in tcl

Tags: tcl

Given a CIDR, how can I convert it to a subnet mask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same way you do in any other language

```
set n 24
set mask [expr {~ 0 << ( 32 - $n )}]
format "%d.%d.%d.%d" [expr {$mask >> 24 & 255}] [expr {$mask >> 16 & 255}] [expr {$mask >> 8 & 255}] [expr {$mask & 255}]
```

Comment: Thanks.  What does set mask line actually do ?

Comment: It creates a mask of "bits" that get shifted around, truly working with the data as a bitmask.

Comment: Related to this question, How can I add 1 to an IP address (Example: 192.168.1.0). I have an IP address and a Subnet mask and I am trying to get the first valid IP address in the range. If I do a logical AND between IP and Subnet, I get the subnet number. I need to add 1 to the subnet number to get the first IP.

Comment: How about the reverse of this? If given a net mask (in hex) how would I get the cidr using tcl?

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's easy to do in plain Tcl, but you may consider using `ip` package from Tcllib for IP addresses transformations as it provides numerous convenience functions that make it easy to almost anything you need to do with IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.